# Can't change onclick dynamically through javascript: bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, onclick, bookmarklet

I've tried to change the onclick function through a bookmarklet in the url using this code:

```
javascript: document.getElementById('Button1').onclick = function(){alert('foo')};void(0);
```

I can change the value of the button but just not the onclick function. Is it even possible?
Thanks ^^

Some notes: I've also tried putting the code in a .js file and creating an external .js file using createElementId but it still does not seem to work :/

Comment: @Jcubed it comes up as document.getElementById('Button1') is null :/

Comment: What browser are you testing ?

Comment: @Joey Google Chrome, though I've tried it with all the other browsers I have

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the trailing semi-colon to terminate the alert call. It's easier to spot once you indent it:

```
document.getElementById('Button1').onclick = function() {
    alert('foo');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works. So the only option is that Button1 is not an ID of an element on that page.

For example:

```
<div id="Button1">Button</div>
```

If an element on the page looks like that, you will get your `alert ('foo');`

Comment: I've already given the id to the button, that's how I'm able to change the value of the button using the same code :/

Comment: sure javascript: document.getElementById('button1').value = "Change";void(0);

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work...

Try to insert this code into the w3schools jseditor http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events

```
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="Button1" onclick="alert('Some action');">Action!!</button>

<button type="button" id="Button2" onclick="document.getElementById('Button1').onclick = function(){alert('another action')};">Change onclick</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm running the bookmarklet on another domain so I cannot edit the html and I'm trying to keep my code short as possible but I'll try to do the createElement('button') and see if that will change it